# C API's for Packages/Binaries integrity check on already installed packages/binaries?

Tags: apt, package-management, debian

debums is verifying from /var/lib/dpkg/info/*md5sums and this file can be modified easily by root user, looking for alternative like database or something else.

Comment: Yes root is required but still we cant believe on user specific integrity check, looking for something like rpmdb or signature verfification.

Comment: `root` user access is generally given to system administrator. I'm not sure why you don't want to believe those files and the root user.

Comment: It is kind of hack, if you believe on one file for verification of package/binary integrity